# Odd WebDAV drive mapping on Windows 7

Tags: 2013, webdav

Our client is trying to use WebDAV to connect to Tridion 2013 SP1 and copy over several images but is getting the usual cryptic errors.

I checked the connection from our internal network and copying images is fine.

I've noticed though that when I map a drive it appears as **http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/webdav** in Windows Explorer. However when the clients maps the drive, it appears as **\\xx.xx.xx.xx@8080\DavWWWRoot***.

The client's mapped drive does work, but it appears to be read-only, they can never copy back.

has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: Are the errors in the Tridion Event Log (on the server) not less cryptic? What kind of errors do you get there?

Comment: That path seems related to [Mini-Director, a Windows WebDAV client](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows). It *might* be okay as-is. Maybe double check permissions for the locations that user is attempting to upload in?

Comment: Our user is a full sys-admin.

Comment: I remember from the old days that the WebDAV client in Windows XP was a bit broken, and for that reason we used MS Word to map the WebDAV drive (since Word had its own WebDAV client which did work). I wouldn't be surprized if there are still multiple WebDAV clients on Windows and if some of them are just plain broken...

Answer (score 3):

Ok -accorinding to my client it was down to a clash in domains - there own internal one and the one setup when we configured Tridion.

The two used the the same name so Windows was defaulting to the internal domain and treating the mapped drive as an internal drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following as i notice few issues because of following.

- Try drag and drop to the folder rather than copy.
- Is Webclient service is running on the client machine?

also try this link.
http://www.yeehawup.com/2011/07/mapping-a-network-drive-to-webdav-share-in-windows-7/